# terminate a processed launched by nohup

Tags: debian, kill, nohup

I have loaded debian etch into my NAS and I am trying to use it to routinely extract information from a website. Since there are quite a lot of pages to download, I used the `nohup` command, like this:

```
nohup ./script.sh $
```

Then the script runs as expected, but suddenly I changed my mind and want to modifiy the script a bit before running it again. How can I terminate the script which is now running?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the pid of the script using:

```
ps aux|grep script.sh
```

Then kill it using

```
kill -15 <the pid>
```

This sends the [SIGTERM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGTERM) signal to the process, which can be caught to allow clean (graceful release of system resources). Alternatively, you can use the [SIGQUIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGQUIT) process with `-3`, which is capable if generating a core file (if you want one).

Comment: `info nohup` said: _"`nohup` runs the given COMMAND with hangup signals ignored"_. So `kill -1` doesn't work.

Comment: @quanta Yes, you're correct.

Answer (score 3):

`nohup` prevents the processes from receiving SIGHUP. So, you must use `-15 (SIGTERM)` or `-9 (SIGKILL)` with `kill` command.

Comment: SIGKILL should only be used as a last resort though, since system resources may not be freed http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Termination-Signals.html